# SQL Server stored procedure error while executing from php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, php-mssql

I am trying to execute a stored procedure from php.

In the php code iam sending a integer parameter to the stored procedure

```
$orderId =824;
$result =mssql_bind($sp, "@orderID", $orderId, SQLINT1, true, false);
```

I getting an error

mssql_execute() [function.mssql-execute]: message: The formal parameter "@orderID" was not declared as an OUTPUT parameter, but the actual parameter passed in requested output. (severity 16)

Can any one  say the reason please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [document of mssql_bind](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-bind.php) gives the signature of it as:

```
bool mssql_bind  ( resource $stmt  , string $param_name  , mixed &$var  , int $type  [, bool $is_output = false  [, bool $is_null = false  [, int $maxlen = -1  ]]] )
```

So your problem is you're setting `$is_output` as true.

Use

```
$orderId =824;
$result =mssql_bind($sp, "@orderID", $orderId, SQLINT1, false, false);
```

Comment: I suspect so, as Linto says "sending an integer parameter to the stored procedure"

Comment: i got everything working ,but one problem.When i sent  small oderid(eg 1,225,100,596,..)it works but when i sent big order id eg(100303),it not giving output, eventhough there is records for this order.So i changed the type parameter of mssql_bind  with all most all  , then i will get the result with a warning "Warning: mssql_execute() [function.mssql-execute]: WARNING! Some character(s) could not be converted into client's character set. Unconverted bytes were changed to question marks ('?'). (severity 16)".Do you have any idea

Comment: Your problem is the SQLINT1 data type. See http://php.net/manual/en/mssql.constants.php. SQLINT1 is a single byte, -128 to 127. Use SQLINT4 instead.

Comment: Thank you very much  SamStephens .My problem is over

Answer (score 0):

You must create your stored procedure so that it indicates that the parameter as an OUTPUT variable.

```
DECLARE MyProc (@orderID int OUTPUT) AS ...
```

Comment: so do i need to create that particular stored proceedure in php code?i mean the stored proceedure from the sql server

Comment: No.  If the stored procedure needs to have the @orderID parameter as an output parameter, you would alter it using the same technique/tool in which it was created.  Are you expecting the stored procedure to send the @orderID value to your PHP code?  If No, then you want to look at @SamStephens answer and leave the procedure unchanged.

Comment: i got everything working ,but one problem.When i sent  small oderid(eg 1,225,100,596,..)it works but when i sent big order id eg(100303),it not giving output, eventhough there is records for this order.So i changed the type parameter of mssql_bind  with all most all  , then i will get the result with a warning "Warning: mssql_execute() [function.mssql-execute]: WARNING! Some character(s) could not be converted into client's character set. Unconverted bytes were changed to question marks ('?'). (severity 16)".Do you have any idea

Comment: Hi bobs , i got the answer for last question from SamStephens Thank you very much  bobs for your interest too.My problem is over